# Getting NullPointer when try to get global ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, global-variables

I got 3 classes.
A main class, globalVariable class, and an item class.

I try to set an ArrayList in the main class. And I want to read it out in the item class.
This is what I tried:

Main:

```
for (int i = data.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if (str_tv.contains(data.get(i).getCaption())){
        //TODO data.remove();
        String str_i = String.valueOf(i);
        checkedArray.add(str_i);

    }
}
System.out.println("MainActivity");
global.setArrList(checkedArray);
System.out.println("size = "+global.getArrList().size());
```

`global.setArrlList` does work here. Also `global.getArrList` works here (I get my size).

Now I try to get it from the item class:

```
System.out.println("Item Class");
System.out.println("size = "+global.getArrList().size());   <--gives NullPointer
```

But here, it isn't working, then it gives a NullPointer.

This is my Global class:

```
ArrayList<String> arrList;

public ArrayList<String> getArrList() {
    return arrList;
}

public void setArrList(ArrayList<String> arrList) {
    this.arrList = arrList;
}
```

I did check if he maybe tried to get the `ArrayList` first instead of setting it. But he shows the `System.out.println("MainActivity");` before the one in the item class.

Why does it give a NullPointer? What am I missing?

Logcat:

```
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at com.dlv.GewasBescherming3.ItemListAdapter.getView(ItemListAdapter.java:47)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2035)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1865)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
01-24 11:02:04.755: E/AndroidRuntime(30097):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add static to it so that it will have that data in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually,

`ArrayList<String> arrList;` is `null`.

Just declare it like `ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();`

**Update:**

Actually both `Main` and `Item` classes **have different global object** so it can not reference to same `arrList`.

I would be better to add:

```
public static ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in `Global class` and use it like this:

```
Global.arrList.size();
```

Comment: And also you are missing basic Java Fundamentals.. :-)

Comment: It worked :) had to change `public static ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();` indeed. but it doesn't work without `static`, what does that `static` mean/do?

Comment: `static` members belong to the class instead of a specific instance.

It means that only one instance of a static field exists even if you create a million instances of the class or you don't create any. It will be shared by all instances.